# Resaltar de color cada palabra seleccionada

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código **HTML**: *(El cual no puede ser modificado)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
                <title>
                    Documento
                </title>
                <style>
                    p {
          color: blue;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
                </style>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
                </script>
            </meta>
        </meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Había una vez un hombre que vivía
        en una pizzería. A este hombre
        le encantaba comer pizza cada día
        y es lo que hacía continuamente.
        Acabó siendo el hombre más feliz
        del mundo. Fin del cuento.
        </p>
        <script src="js/pr1.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y a continuación el código con **JQuery**:

```
$( "p" )
.click( function ( ) {
    $( this )
    .css( "color", "red" )
} );
```

Con el código anterior proporcionado, cuando se hace clic sobre un elemento me pinta de rojo todo el parágrafo, pero lo que yo quiero es que me pinte solo de rojo la palabra seleccionada del texto, no todo.

He intentado varios métodos pero no me funcionan, por lo que el código que hay, es lo mas simplificado que lo he podido hacer. Cualquier solución para aprender como se hace me ayudaría. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Tomar el texto dentro del `p`
- Separar la cadena en palabras
- Cada palabra ponerla dentro de, por ejemplo, un `<span>`
- Luego agregar un evento a la espera de un `click` sobre dichos elementos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let $p = $('p'),
  texto = $p.text().trim(), // Obtenemos el texto en el <p>
  palabras = texto.split(' '), // Obtenemos un arreglo de palabras
  spans = palabras.map(p => `<span>${p}</span> `); // Metemos las palabras en <span>

// Metemos los <span> dentro del <p>
$p.html(spans);

// Suscribimos una funcion para escuchar el click sobre los <span>
$p.on('click', 'span', function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```css
p {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Había una vez un hombre que vivía en una pizzería. A este hombre le encantaba comer pizza cada día y es lo que hacía continuamente. Acabó siendo el hombre más feliz del mundo. Fin del cuento.
</p>
```

Comment: Perfecto @Marcos, era justo lo que necesitaba, no sabía que el uso del map se empleaba para este tipo de casos en concreto.